# Control the color order and draw a line at y=0

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot from these 2 sets of data. This is working, except the color. I am trying to match the colors of ufiles and dfiles, so that line from ufile[1] and dfiles[1] will have same color.

How I can get that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# import np
import pylab

ufiles = ["dos_u_Co.dat",  "dos_u_Fe.dat",  "dos_u_Re.dat",  "dos_u_tot.dat"]
dfiles = ["dos_d_Co.dat",  "dos_d_Fe.dat",  "dos_d_Re.dat",  "dos_d_tot.dat"]
colors = ('b', 'g', 'r','c')


datalist = [ ( pylab.loadtxt(filename)) for filename in ufiles ]
for data in datalist:
    pylab.plot( data[:,0], data[:,1], label=datalist)

datalist = [ ( pylab.loadtxt(filename)) for filename in dfiles ]
for data in datalist:
    pylab.plot( data[:,0], -1*data[:,1], label=datalist)

pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cycle through `colors` as you cycle though `datalist` using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), and then set the plot colour using the `color` kwarg:

```
import pylab

ufiles = ["dos_u_Co.dat",  "dos_u_Fe.dat",  "dos_u_Re.dat",  "dos_u_tot.dat"]
dfiles = ["dos_d_Co.dat",  "dos_d_Fe.dat",  "dos_d_Re.dat",  "dos_d_tot.dat"]
colors = ('b', 'g', 'r','c')


datalist = [ ( pylab.loadtxt(filename)) for filename in ufiles ]
for data, color in zip(datalist, colors):
    pylab.plot( data[:,0], data[:,1], color=color, label=datalist)

datalist = [ ( pylab.loadtxt(filename)) for filename in dfiles ]
for data, color in zip(datalist, colors):
    pylab.plot( data[:,0], -1*data[:,1], color=color, label=datalist)

pylab.show()
```

Comment: Dear tom: thanks a lot.

Comment: Just one more thing: can you please also add a line to set xlim, ylim? 
I have tried `pylab.set_xlim=([-4, 3])
pylab.ylim=([-4, 3])`
 but none of them has any effect

Comment: remove the `=` from your lines above, e.g. `pylab.xlim([-4, 3])`